# Node-RED is there any way how to create sub-category in palette

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am new to node-red, Is there away to create sub-category or a tree structure in palette for my custom nodes
Please help me...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, the node-red palette has a single level of hierarchy.